# How do I show a user the app is working on making a network connection?

Tags: android, connection

When trying to connect to a server, my app does not have a very appealing interface. I don't want to display progress because it doesn't really make sense to me but I want to show the user the app has not frozen. Using other apps I have seen the interface say 'connecting' and a spinning wheel to show it is working. How do I show the user that the app is working on establishing the connection and has not frozen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're after is a progress dialog with indeterminate progress.  This can be achieved with a single line of code:

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, "", 
                                            "Loading. Please wait...", true);
dialog.show();
```

and, when you're done,

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

This will show a dialog like this over your activity.  Remember, that you should do the time-consuming communication asynchronously, otherwise your app will look frozen.  If you do the communication on the main UI thread, the dialog will not be shown.

[image]

Comment: oh man, that looks exactly like what I am looking for. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a Async task?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html

That has a hook for updating the UI thread with progress, and using it means Android won't think your UI has frozen and offer to kill the app.

Comment: yes, I am using a background thread to establish a connection. I don't have problems with my app freezing because of that. The asynctask didn't make sense to me because I am not downloading an image or something, my app just needs to work on establishing a connection. I want some kind of widget on the screen to spin and show that the app is working on a connection. Is asynctask the class I want to use to accomplish this? I am not looking for a progress bar.